# Does a phrase like "close to or within X" require commas to set off the "or within"?

Tags: punctuation

If I were to say something like:

> close to or within X

does it need to be written:

> close to, or within, X

I encounter this type of construction in lot in scientific writing and I'm never sure if it needs to be punctuated or if it's just a stylistic preference. I've been googling to no avail because I'm not exactly sure how to describe it.

Comment: Commas are sometimes added for clarity or to resolve an ambiguity, but with a sentence fragment that can't be determined. Related – [Is the phrase, "Use commas sparingly" a valid piece of advice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20592/is-the-phrase-use-commas-sparingly-a-valid-piece-of-advice) That question has more links in its own 'Related' panel.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer I was searching for in this thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417198/should-data-is-read-from-and-written-to-disk-have-commas?rq=1

Comment: @WeatherVane seeing as I just linked that exact thread and said that it answered my question, yes lol

Comment: That's why I voted to close as a duplicate: you said it was. The comment (and its upticks) is generated automatically.

Comment: Zero offsetting punctuation for parentheticals is a reasonable option _when the parenthetical is short and no loss of clarity / no increased difficulty in parsing occur/s_.